# Help running power through a switch to a light, but continuing power along the circuit to an outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an unfinished electrical project I inherited that I want to complete, I just wanted to check and make sure the wiring diagram I've fuddled together below will work. I want to run power through a switch to a light, but continue the circuit over to an outlet receptacle.

The wires have already been run to the boxes, so I'm trying to piece together what my predecessor's plans were.

Am I doing this right?

[image: hashed up diagram of light on a circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it right. I'm assuming you don't want the outlet to be switched. If you run 12/2 as indicated you can make it either a 15amp or 20amp circuit. With 14/2 it can only be 15amp. If the outlet is in a bathroom or kitchen it must be 20 amp and must be GFCI protected.

Comment: Note, too, that the ground wire squiggle in the light fixture box should be connected to the box if it's metal and/or to the fixture itself.

Comment: @HoneyDo: Thanks, yes, I don't want the outlet to be switched, just to have power. The cable is 12/2. The outlets are in a simple shed outbuilding, nothing fancy like a bathroom or kitchen. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If in a shed you might want to check local codes on amperage required and the need for GFCI protection. Either way I would suggest you run 12/2 and 20amp circuit as well as add a GFCI for a shed.

Answer (score 2):

Colored tape is your very best friend.  Let's re-color wires for **purpose**:

- White for neutral (required by Code anyway)
- Black for *always*-hot
- Red for *switched*-hot as a lamp would use.

[image]